# Escape to collapse search and fix a visual bug in the search box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, top-bar

Two things:

1. Is it possible to make it so that the search box collapses if you press the Escape key? If it is expanded, but I decide that I want to go to Questions, I have to first click somewhere else on the page to make it collapse.
2. I'm on Windows 7 and when I snap the browser to the side, the search box just appears as a box with no context. It just looks weird. Maybe you can just put the magnifying glass icon back when the viewport width is below a certain size? See the following image:

   [image: What is this?]

Comment: Oh no. They [brought back the auto-expanding search box](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101387/please-tone-down-or-remove-the-auto-expansion-of-the-search-box)? That was a bad dream many years ago.

Comment: 1) yea, that makes sense. will put it on todo list. 2) that's gonna be fixed before launch.

Comment: 2) should be fixed now.

Comment: @Paweł Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. You can now collapse the search field with the escape key.